# detect if draggable element is hovering another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few divs spreaded in my body:

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

which are all draggable with jqueryUI:

```
var $divs = $('#one, #two, #three');
$divs.draggable({ start: dragStart,
                  cursor: 'move',     
                  stop: dragStop,
                  drag: whileDrag });
```

i would like to fire an event if the currently dragged element is dragged over one of the divs. But not like jqueryUI's `droppable` where you have to stop the drag to fire. It should fire while draggin! Is there any other method except to read the offset live?

Any help is much appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DvU6f/2)

```
// function to determine, that rectangles intersect
var intersect = function(a,b){
    return(
            (
              (
                ( a.x >= b.x && a.x <= b.x1 ) || ( a.x1 >= b.x && a.x1 <= b.x1  )
              ) && (
                ( a.y >= b.y && a.y <= b.y1 ) || ( a.y1 >= b.y && a.y1 <= b.y1 )
              )
            ) || (
                   (
                     ( b.x >= a.x && b.x <= a.x1 ) || ( b.x1 >= a.x && b.x1 <= a.x1  )
                   ) && (
                     ( b.y >= a.y && b.y <= a.y1 ) || ( b.y1 >= a.y && b.y1 <= a.y1 )
                   )
                 )
            ) || (
                  (
                    (
                      ( a.x >= b.x && a.x <= b.x1 ) || ( a.x1 >= b.x && a.x1 <= b.x1  )
                    ) && (
                      ( b.y >= a.y && b.y <= a.y1 ) || ( b.y1 >= a.y && b.y1 <= a.y1 )
                    )
            ) || (
                  (
                   ( b.x >= a.x && b.x <= a.x1 ) || ( b.x1 >= a.x && b.x1 <= a.x1  )
                  ) && (
                   ( a.y >= b.y && a.y <= b.y1 ) || ( a.y1 >= b.y && a.y1 <= b.y1 )
                  )
               )
            );
}

// elements - elements to fire dragover event on draggable element hover 
var coordinates = {},
    elements = ['#two', '#three'];
    $('#one').draggable({
        start: dragStart,
        cursor: 'move',
        stop: dragStop,
        create: function(event, ui){
            for (var k in elements){
                coordinates[k] = {
                    x: $(elements[k]).offset().left,
                    y: $(elements[k]).offset().top,
                    x1: $(elements[k]).offset().left + $(elements[k])[0].clientWidth,
                    y1: $(elements[k]).offset().top + $(elements[k])[0].clientHeight
                }
            }
        },
        drag: function(event, ui){
            var draggableElementCoord = {
                x: ui.offset.left,
                y: ui.offset.top,
                x1: ui.offset.left + ui.helper[0].clientWidth,
                y1: ui.offset.top + ui.helper[0].clientHeight
            };
            for (var k in elements){
                if (intersect(coordinates[k], draggableElementCoord)){
                    $(elements[k]).trigger('dragover');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Using:

```
$(document).on('dragover', '#two', function(e){
  // your code
});
```

Comment: first thanks for your answer. i considered that way with `offset()` as you said before i have made this question, but i thought there would be an easier way. To your second conclusion, it doesnt work. actually i dont know what `dragover` in your case is. I dont find anything about it in the documentation of JqueryUI? Could you explain, maybe it'll help!

Comment: dragover - standard JS event, fired if dragged element hovered on more element. But apparently plugin not fire this event.

Comment: I can help you with the first variant.

Comment: I add full first realization variant

Comment: wow, thanks for that! unfortanetly i cant check it right now anymore, but i will test in a couple of hours! glad you help!

Comment: one more thing, is it possible for you to use jquery instead of raw javascript at some points! its quite easier to read them, and im not that average! i dont mind if not!

Comment: i accepted the answer because the fiddle works exactly how i wanted! thank you very much!